# debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1" Imported dependencies cannot be imported Test

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.4.1"
```

Imported dependencies cannot be imported Test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZqBb.png)

```
class MainActivityTest {

@Before
fun setUp() {
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
}

@Test
fun name() {
   ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
}
```

}

```
If you don't introduce this dependency, there will be no problem
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWDVm.png)

I'm going to use FragmentScenario here

I am according to the official   https://github.com/android/architecture-samples